# JSONP endpoint with some protection

Tags: json, ajax, jsonp, jwt

I have an endpoint that returns JSON, which I use on a site with AJAX.

I want to use the same endpoint from other sites (running on different domains), so I want to convert it into JSONP with a callback.

The data is not sensitive and doesn't need extensive security. However, I want to make it as difficult as possible for other sites to use the endpoint directly in their sites. (I realize that they can technically use almost any internet accessible endpoint through server side code or reverse proxy).

What's the best way to accomplish that?

One idea I had is to add a [JWT](http://jwt.io/) token as a parameter. The token would be served on sites that use the endpoint. Would that make sense? Is there a better practice to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CORS instead of JSONP would give you more control of the json being accessed by websites, however it wouldn't stop *servers* from accessing the json at all, meaning bypassing it would simply mean using something like YQL to get the data, or their own server.

JWT would however solve that problem, assuming each JWT would expire relatively quickly.

Comment: @Keven B: Thanks. CORS is only IE 10+, so in my case it's out. For JWT, the way I envision it is that it would be loaded from the server with the page and then used by subsequent JavaScript calls. If the JWT expiration is long, another developer would still not be able to use the endpoint as part of his client side code, right? And if they are going through the trouble of using server side code to steal the JWT token, then no one can really protect against that. So, what would be the advantage of a quick expiration?

Comment: Nothing would stop a developer from viewing your source or network requests to get said token. A quick expiration minimizes that problem

Comment: Of course. What I meant is a slow expiration, say a day vs. a quick expiration like one minute. If it is a day, the developer's code would still have be to be updated daily or the JWT needs to be fetched by server side code and cached, right? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. By short i meant, say, 30min to 2 hours, day works too, just a matter of how hard do you want to make it for those using your data in an unauthorized way. 1 day vs 30min isn't much different from an attacker's point of view, just changes the interval at which they need to request a new token.

Comment: Thanks! I will also look at CORS too since it apparently works with IE8+ (my understanding was inaccurate). Maybe create a hybrid solution that detects browser version and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your server as a WebService that accepts requests from all or a whitelist of domains...

You should read this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: My understanding is that CORS can only be used with only modern browsers, which would be a deal breaker for me.

Comment: CORS can be used in ie 8+, just not with xhr